# Issues with simple insert statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on this code and i am using a simple insert statement and I cant figure out why its not working.  If anyone could see what I am doing wrong please let me know.  Thanks!
This is the error I am getting:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL     server version for the right syntax to use near 'long,comments) 
VALUES (2 ,2012-11-18 21:25:30, 39.3436984, -76.5856958, hh)' at line 1
```

here is the code:

```
 mysql_query ("INSERT INTO incidents (emergency_type,date_time,lat,long,comments)  
VALUES  (2 ,$catchDate, $catchLat, $catchLong, $catchDescription)") or die(mysql_error());   
 echo"<br /> Data inserted";
```

Comment: That was it, Thanks Laurence!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long is a reserved word, try `long` surrounded with backticks instead.

Reference https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

A quick browse around the docs reveals that you should be investigating [PDO::prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [PDO::execute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) to do this. Your current method appears to be vulnerable to SQL injection.

I'm not a PHP programmer, but something like:

```
$db = get a db handle from somewhere
$st = $db->prepare('Insert Into Incidents (emergency_type, date_time, lat, `long`, comments) Values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
$st->execute(array(2 ,$catchDate, $catchLat, $catchLong, $catchDescription));
```

Comment: And better yet, if this is your own table, change those column names to `longitude` and `latitude`.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO incidents (emergency_type,date_time,lat,`long`,comments)  
VALUES  (2 ,$catchDate, $catchLat, $catchLong, '$catchDescription')
```

`LONG` is on the list of [MySQL Reserved Keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). Escape it with backtick instead.

One more thing, values for `date_time` and `comments` *must be enclosed with single quotes* as they are not numeric.

and you query is now vulnerable with `SQL Injection`, please take time t read the article below

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: Oh, is that interpolating strings rather than binding parameters? The poster should look for a different way of calling if that's the case.

Comment: @Laurence yep,but at the moment, the asker is not parameterizing the query.

Answer (score 0):

[LONG is a keyword/reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) in mysql. You can use backticks to escape it

```
INSERT INTO incidents (emergency_type,date_time,lat,`long`,comments)
```

Or change your table column name to `longitude`